# Prevent CTRL V in HTML Editor Ajax Control MS

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I am using in C# HTML EDITOR Control MS Ajax.

I would like to know if is possible FORCE the control HTML EDITOR to DO NOT ACCEPT text from PASTE (short cut ctrl+v or menu command).

My aim is to prevent css inline code to be added to the text.

I would allow user to add text if pasted just with HTML EDITOR Button PASTE PLAIN TEXT.

Any ideas?
Do you think it is a good solution or any others= thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trap the keypress event and check for CTRL+V.

Comment: I haven't used that control before so I don't know the exact event names and parameters; I'm also guessing that this will be used in a browser so you will need to use javascript. Google 'javascript onkeypress event' or check this SO thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/929729/javascript-onkeypress.